# Python Newbie: How to create a progressbar with topwindow module that can show the diffrence between two times(minutes)?

Tags: python, pys60

Ive just started learning programming in python esp. Pys60, I was wondering if it was possible in pys60, (I hope people still remember pys60). It would help me a lot to create my app. Please keep the code simple, i may not understand it clearly 
            -  cheers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native GUI on symbian 60 has no progress bar so you have to build it yourself using a drawing canvas. Here is a website with an example and python s60 source code:
http://croozeus.com/blogs/?p=1103

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was sort of what I was looking for but not exactly, the code was based on a range I dont think it was based on time functions. I want to give a brief description: I'm from Nepal, its power source is fully dependent upon hydro power now the winter is commencing and the rivers are going to freeze and We get about 5 to 10 hrs of power cut every day. So, i want a script that can show a timebar[like progress bars] than runs according to minutes. So, i can know how much is time left for the power cut to end or start again. I Hope im not asking too much

Comment: If you are looking for a Symbian app, this is the wrong place. This site is for software developers who build things. If you want to build a timebar app for Symbian, the example that I pointed you to has everything that you need, except for the time which is highly likely to be easily available from another api. Normally you can do import time; time.time() to get the time in seconds from Python.

Comment: I'm not looking for a app but Im looking for a core script concept for the app. Anyway, I browsed through  croozeus and got some nice tutorials and I found lots of helpful snippets from dzone, thanks for that answer. By the way, do you know how not to make the signal, operater title and other things disappear from the s60 2nd ed homescreen. Am I missing something? Here is one of my scripts http://wapnep.bplaced.net/wFtp.py Ftp uploader script I made to upload my files to the free webspace, it works but Ive not finished it yet and why cant I set a exit key handler???